# How does one auto-complete forms in Microsoft Edge in Microsoft 10 21H2?

Tags: windows-10, autocomplete, microsoft-edge, forms

How does one auto-complete forms in Microsoft Edge in Microsoft 10 21H2?

When I click on an auto-completion entry, nothing happens:

[image]

Using Edge Version 99.0.1150.46 (Official build) (64-bit). Auto-completing forms works on Chrome.

---

Full screenshot:

[image]

Comment: What extensions do you have?  It should simply work.  Have you considered performing a Reset of Edge? I assume Chrome autofill works the same website?

Comment: Look in Control Panel, Credentials and see if the user and password is there, or there in a different way.

Comment: @Ramhound  0 extensions, I just installed Windows 2 minutes before that.

Comment: Is this a Edge profile that had been synchronized into the cloud? You saved the credentials before you attempted to use them? I ask because it doesn’t look like the autofill icon for Edge

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, the Edge profile had not been synchronized into the cloud. Credentials  were saved 1 min before when completing a similar form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now, I guess it was just some temporary glitch:

[image]